# HTML AUDIO Error

Tags: html

Error: Element source not allowed as child of element audio in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
    <figure> <img src="assets/orangutan2.jpg" alt=Rainforest>
        <br /><audio controls>
    <hr>
    <source src="assets/rainforest_ambience-GlorySunz-1938133500.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="assets/rainforest_ambience-GlorySunz-1938133500.ogg" type="audio/ogg">    
    Your browser does not support this audio element.
        </audio>

        <figcaption>Here is the audio for a rainforest</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Comment: Your `<hr>` is not valid where it is.

Comment: thanks so much man lol just a stupid little error